# JPanel not showing up on JFrame if added as a class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a JButton to a JPanel that I create as a class, like so:

```
public class Popup extends Main {

    public Popup() {
        JPanel popup = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("SUPER COOL BUTTON");
        popup.add(button);
        popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
private void createFrame() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEAM PROJECT");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new Popup(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I do this, the frame creates but has nothing in it.  Similar code works when trying to draw on the panel using `paintComponent`, so is the problem that you can't add `SwingComponents` this way?

What can I do to get the `JPanel` created in `Popup` to be added to the frame created in `Main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you extend Main (as that appears to be the class where you create the JFrame)?

If you want to add a button to a panel then extend JPanel and add your button to your class (which is a JPanel already so there is no need to create another JPanel):

```
public class Popup extends JPanel {

    public Popup() {
        //JPanel popup = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("SUPER COOL BUTTON");
        add( button );
        //popup.add(button);
        //popup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem was also that i was adding the button to popup.  Thank you for your quick response! I'll accept this answer as soon as stack overflow let's me

Comment: @wanderer0810 no, the problem is that the created JPanel was not being added to the JFrame. It was just created.

Comment: Also your class Main, should not extend JPanel. Main is just a class that you use to create your frame so it doesn't need to extend anything. You only extend a class when you add functionality to it.